# How do I remove text in a label in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am working on a login GUI, and want to remove the data you typed when you create an account or login with incorrect data, but the function that I have set doesn't work. I have it print when it is run and that is working, but it doesn't remove the data inside the label. Here is the code.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        print(self.username.text, self.password.text)


class CreateWindow(Screen):
    createusername = ObjectProperty(None)
    createpassword = ObjectProperty(None)

    def createAccountButton(self):
        createdusername = str(self.createusername.text)
        createdpassword = str(self.createpassword.text)
        with open("database.txt", "a") as database:
            database.write(createdusername + "," + createdpassword + '\n')
            print("In file now")
            database.close()
        self.resetType()
    
    def resetType(self):
        self.createusername.txt = ""
        self.createpassword.txt = ""
        print("Working")

class RealWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("login.kv")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #kivy has a default app class, so no need to create one
    TestApp().run()





WindowManager:
    #: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
    transition: NoTransition()
    transition: NoTransition()
    LoginWindow:
    CreateWindow:
    RealWindow:


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"
    username: username
    password: password

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Log In"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.3}
            on_press: root.btn()
        
        Button:
            text:"Create Account"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.36, "y":0.20}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Create"
        
        TextInput:
            id: password
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.5}
        
        TextInput:
            id:username
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '40'
            text:"Log In"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Username:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Password:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.5}

<CreateWindow>:
    name: "Create"

    createusername: createusername
    createpassword: createpassword

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Login"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.3}
            on_press: root.createAccountButton()
            on_press: root.resetType
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"
        
        TextInput:
            id: createpassword
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.5}
        
        TextInput:
            id:createusername
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '40'
            text:"Create Account"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Username:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Password:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.5}

<RealWindow>:
    name: "Real"
```

I am working on loading and reading passwords and usernames right now, so it isn't finished.

Comment: Typo: it is `self.createusername.text = ""` and 
        `self.createpassword.text = ""` not `self.createusername.txt = ""` and 
        `self.createpassword.txt = ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FJSevilla mentions it in the comment, you can fix your bug by changing `self.createusername.txt = ""` to `self.createusername.text = ""` and `self.createpassword.txt = ""` not  and `self.createpassword.text = ""`.

Nevertheless, the way you use the `ObjectProperty` to link the Python file to the kv file could be improved. Indeed, you don't need to create the `ObjectProperty`, you can simply access to the widgets of the `.kv` file with their ids.

For instance, you can change the class `CreateWindow` to:

```py
class CreateWindow(Screen):

    def createAccountButton(self):
        createdusername = str(self.ids.createusername.text)
        createdpassword = str(self.ids.createpassword.text)
        with open("database.txt", "a") as database:
            database.write(createdusername + "," + createdpassword + '\n')
            print("In file now")
            database.close()
        self.resetType()
    
    def resetType(self):
        self.ids.createusername.text = "" # Access to the ids set in the .kv file
        self.ids.createpassword.text = ""
        print("Working")
```

and in the kv file:

```
<CreateWindow>:
    name: "Create"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Login"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.3}
            on_press: root.createAccountButton()
            on_press: root.resetType
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"
        
        TextInput:
            id: createpassword
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.5}
        
        TextInput:
            id: createusername
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '40'
            text:"Create Account"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Username:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Password:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.5}
```